# Change windows computer name from command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

Is it possible to change the computer name of a Windows XP or Windows Vista/7 machine from the command prompt.

So for example the command line equivalent of the following in XP.
"Start >> right click My Computer >> Properties >> Computer Name tab >> Change... >> Computer Name field >> new computer name ".

Thanks
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSKB 298593: How To Use the Netdom.exe Utility to Rename a Computer in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298593) says this:

```
netdom renamecomputer machine /newname:new_computername /userd:domainname\administrator_id /passwordd:* /usero:local_admin /passwordo:* /reboot:seconds before automatic reboot
```

> A description of the preceding command line is:
>
> **Machine** is the current name of the computer.
>
> **New_computername** is the name that the computer is going to have.
>
> **Domainname\administrator_id** is the network basic input/output system (NetBIOS) domain name  and the administrator identification (ID) of a user account that has administrative permissions to the computer object in the domain.
>
> **Local_admin** is a user that has local administrative permissions, which can be the same account specified for /userd:
>
> **The asterisk symbol (*)** is the value that is connected to the /passwordd: and /passwordo: parameters and specifies that the password should be typed with hidden characters when the command is submitted.
>
> **Time before automatic reboot in seconds** is the amount of time before the computer restarts after renaming the computer. If this parameter is not specified, the computer must be restarted manually.

For Windows XP, you need the Support Tools included on the installation media under the Support\Tools folder. For Vista/7, netdom.exe is included by default.

Answer (score 2):

This command should do just that:
`netdom renamecomputer CURRENTNAME /newname:NEWNAME`

Just replace the words I put in caps with the current name of the machine and the name you would like it to have.

Note that you may need to reboot for the change to happen.